# Im trying to insert a data into database using vb

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, visual-studio, command

I am trying to add a new data in mySql database using vb . But the error always says [unit_type] is not allowed to be null . I even changed the column's setting in the main database . I disabled the not null checkbox .

```vb
Dim datetoday = Date.Today

Try
    command = "INSERT INTO assets_table ([date_created], [unit_type]) VALUES ('" & datetoday & "' , '" & frm_viewAssets.lbl_fetch.Text & "')"

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(command, myconn.open())

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("date_created", CType(datetoday, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("unit_type", CType(frm_viewAssets.lbl_fetch.Text, String)))

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myconn.close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        myconn.close()
    End Try
```

Comment: Argh! Why are you converting a `Date` to a `String`? What is the data type of that `date_created` column? If it's a text type, why? If it's a date type, why are you not inserting a `Date` value?

Answer (score 0):

You did the right thing by trying to use parameters but you did it wrong. You added the parameters to the command but, instead of using parameter place-holders in your SQL, you still inserted the literal values. This:

```vb
command = "INSERT INTO assets_table ([date_created], [unit_type]) VALUES ('" & datetoday & "' , '" & frm_viewAssets.lbl_fetch.Text & "')"
```

should be this:

```vb
command = "INSERT INTO assets_table ([date_created], [unit_type]) VALUES (@date_created, @unit_type)"
```

and then I think that you will need to add the "@" prefix to the parameter names when you create them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the database objects local so you can be sure they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks will handle that for you even if there is an error.

Don't open the connection until directly before the .Execute.

I assumed the type of date_created to be a `Date`.

It can improve the efficiency of your sql to include the datatypes of your parameters.

If all you are doing in your Try/Catch is closing the connection you are just swallowing errors.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim datetoday = Date.Today
    Dim Command = "INSERT INTO assets_table ([date_created], [unit_type]) VALUES (@date_created , @unit_type);"
    Using myconn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand(Command, myconn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_created", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = datetoday
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@unit_type", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = frm_viewAssets.lbl_fetch.Text
        myconn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```